# Creating parent and child at the same time. Flask SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have created the model below to store user and profile data separately in my database

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    profile = db.relationship('Profile', backref='Profile', uselist=False)

class Profile(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(25))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(25))
    email = db.Column(db.String(25), unique=True)
    phone_number = db.Column(db.String(25), unique=True)
    post_code = db.Column(db.String(25))
    house_number = db.Column(db.String(25))
    user = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

I have attempted to populate Profile Model via this method, however, it does not work.

```
@routes.route('/register', methods = ['POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        data = request.get_json()
        new_user = User(username = data['username'], password = data['password'])
        new_user.profile.first_name = data['first_name']
        new_user.profile.last_name = data['last_name']
        new_user.profile.email = data['email']
        new_user.profile.phone_number = data['phone_number']
        new_user.profile.post_code = data['post_code']
        new_user.profile.house_number = data['house_number']
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
             
        return {'msg' : 'sucess'}
```

I get this error, would you please explain what I am doing wrong? I noticed that User.profile column is not present inside my database, however, I thought that was normal for a ForiegnKey?

```
  File "C:\routes\register.py", line 11, in register
    new_user.profile.first_name = data['first_name']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'first_name'
```

What is the solution ? I am assuming I need to create Profile() model separately but how do I simultaneously link that to an uncommitted User() model?

Comment: You can create the profile and pass it to the user when creating it.  `profile = Profile(...); user = User(username='user1', password='hello', profile=profile)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ways to do this, but you probably want to create an `__init__(...)` for user where you initialize a `Profile` object.

Something like this...

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    profile = db.relationship('Profile', backref='Profile', uselist=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.profile = Profile()
```

Comment: This worked like a treat, do you have any resources I could read through to better understand what's going on?